# Is there a measure of 'evenness' of dispersion?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I looked up on the web, but couldn't find anything helpful.

I'm basically looking for a way to measure how 'evenly' a value is distributed. As in, an **'evenly'** distributed distribution like **X**:
[image]

and an **'unevenly'** distributed distribution **Y** of roughly the same mean and standard deviation:
[image]

But is there any evenness measure m, such that m(X) > m(Y)? If there isn't, what would be the best way to create a measure like that?

(Images screenshot from Khan Academy)

Comment: The two examples given have similar *means* but quite different standard deviations.

Comment: It could be. I hope it conveyed the point regarding evenness though.

Comment: Just a thought from a non-statistitian, but what if you have your finite data set (listed in increasing order) $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and you consider the correlation coefficient of the $(i,x_i)$'s?

Comment: Hi Nick. Could you please elaborate a little on this.

Comment: I was just thinking that if your data are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, they will of course fall on the line $y=x$ if plotted the way I suggested. If they are 1,1,1,6,7,7,7 the correlation coefficient will be quite low. The way you're talking about evenness sounds like "can the points be arranged into something 'close to' an arithmetic sequence?" to me.

Comment: Well. The example is just what came on top of my head to make my point regarding the evenness issue. Linearity is not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the time though!

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: As I suggest in my answer below, I think it would really help us suggest an appropriate measure if you could come up with an example of two sets with the same standard deviation that you feel are not equally _even_. I know it's a pain, but I do think it would help you get your answer more quickly! Oh, also, what's the significance of it being a sequence? Is the order particularly important in terms of your notion of _even-ness_?

Comment: Oh - I understand better now with those pictures. By more even, you don't really mean closer to the mean - you basically mean a distribution closer to uniform. I'll think on that. Maybe this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/how-does-one-measure-the-non-uniformity-of-a-distribution

Comment: For a given set of possible values, I want to basically model how 'rare' or 'peculiar' it would be have a particular value from that set of values. In lack of any other options, I'm trying to measure how evenly or uniformly distributed the values are. The more even the distribution, the less chance there is to have any peculiar value from the set. Whereas, if for example all the data lies in the extremes of a distribution, any value can be something worthy to be considered as 'peculiar'. I hope you get it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a widely used method to measure this, but this idea may be useful:

First, assuming that you have the values of $X$ in increasing order, compute $X'$: $x'_k=x_{k+1}-x_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n-1$. Then compute the standard deviation of $X'$.

If the data are perfectly evenly distributed, this measure will be $0$.

To avoid ambiguity, I'll write the formula:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2}{n-1}-\bar x'^2}$$

where $\bar x'$ is the mean of $X'$, that is:
$$\bar x'=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\frac{x_n-x_1}{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks. This looks interesting for sure! I'll have to test it to verify.

Comment: Are you acquainted with machine learning? I could ask you a more direct question, which will save me a lot of time.

Comment: For a given set of possible values, I want to basically model how 'rare' or 'peculiar' it would be have a particular value from that set of values. In lack of any other options, I'm trying to measure how evenly or uniformly distributed the values are. The more even the distribution, the less chance there is to have any peculiar value from the set. Whereas, if for example all the data lies in the extremes of a distribution, any value can be something worthy to be considered as 'peculiar'. I hope you get it?

Comment: Computer Science interpretation: compute the standard deviation of the differences between each adjacent value in a sorted list.

But here's a fun question: what if your values are vectors? E.g., 2D or 3D points in space?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think standard deviation is exactly what you're looking for and you have made an error in calculating them to be the same in your example.

The mean of $X$ is $25/6$ and the standard deviation is approximately $2.3$.

The meany of $Y$ is $23/6$ and the standard deviation is approximately $3.1$.

As you can see, as $Y$ is more *spread out*, it has a higher standard deviation.

EDIT - since you feel that *even-ness* is not adequately captured with just the standard deviation, I might recommend the kurtosis, which is the fourth standardized moment. Here are what distributions that differ on kurtosis look like

[image: kurtosis distributions]

Comment: Thanks for the time. But that's not what I'm looking for. I was actually thinking the same for about a month now, when I realized that 2 sequences that are distributed pretty differently, can have the same std and the mean. So, I now need this extra measure for disambiguation.

Comment: Have you considered other central moments? The first is mean, the second is standard deviation, the third is skewness, the fourth is kurtosis. Kurtosis relates to the weights in the tails, so that might be what you're after.

Comment: I think Kurtosis is for measuring how dense the distribution is around the mean. Correct me if I'm wrong here. It doesn't tell you unambiguously if the distribution is otherwise 'even' throughout its range or not. Though it could be useful. I'll have to test it out to see.

Comment: I think you understand kurtosis basically correctly. I suppose I'm not quite sure exactly what you want your measure to do. For the example you've given, the standard deviation measure is sufficient. Maybe provide a more complicated example for which the standard deviation is equal but you feel one is more _even_ than the other?

Comment: Hi. Please refer to the images I've added to the question.